# Model Prediciton: Incompatible Shape and tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZXfr.png)

I got this error but I don't know what is the issue.

```
r = model.fit(
X_train,
Y_train,
epochs=100,
validation_data=(X_test,Y_test),
```

)

Comment: Please,add some code explaining what are those variables. In addition to this, share code o errors as code instead of screen shots. And finally, and more important, try to do some basic research before asking

Comment: please provide the code that you used for model creation along with train data shapes.

Comment: According to your error image, it looks like the input shape required is (None,None,1) but in your declaration it is set as (None,12,5) which is clearly mentioned in the error. Once you reshape your array, you will get through.